# Copying the styling results of one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of identical size, `df_a` and `df_b`. `df_a` only contains numbers and is styled using a colormap (either using xlsxwriter or pandas styling). `df_b` contains mixed values. Is it possible to copy the resulting style from one dataframe to the other such that the background color of `df_b[i,j]` equals the background color of `df_a[i,j]`?

In the example below the first element of `df_b` should be red, the second yellow, and so on.

[image: example]

Formatting code for `df_a` (based on the xlsxwriter example)

```
# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'col_b': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df_a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:C8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I do think you should include the code where you style `df_a`.

Comment: I have added some code for the xlsxwriter approach, but I am in no way bound to this.

Comment: I don't see any feature in the [xlsxwriter format class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format) that would allow you to read the format of a workbook. I think you would need to store the outputs of your conditional formatting, save them, then call up that json or csv when you want to reapply them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use Pandas' `style` to format the data:

```
# This will color every column into 3-category color
def style(df):
    s = {}
    for c1, c2 in zip(df.columns, df_a.columns):
        s[c1] = pd.cut(df_a[c2], bins=3, 
                          labels=[f'background-color:{c}' for c in ['red','blue','green']])
    return pd.DataFrame(s)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
df_a.style.apply(style, axis=None).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df_a', index=False)
df_b.style.apply(style, axis=None).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df_b', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It was not exactly what I was looking for, but that's my fault for simplifying the question a bit. It did, however, inspire me to find the solution that I needed (see separate answer). Since you did provide an answer to my qestion, I will accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

This solution expands the accepted solution to more than one column and uses a color map instead of a predefined limited set of colors.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib

np.random.seed(24)
df_a = pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_b= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

cm = sns.color_palette("Spectral", as_cmap=True)


def style(df):
    data = df_a.values
    data_normalized = (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))
    bg_colors = cm(data_normalized)
    bg_colors = np.apply_along_axis(matplotlib.colors.to_hex, 2, bg_colors)
    s = pd.DataFrame(bg_colors, columns=df.columns)
    for col in s.columns:
        s[col] = s[col].apply(lambda c: f'background-color:{c}')
    return s


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('temp.xlsx')
df_a.style.apply(style, axis=None).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df_a', index=False)
df_b.style.apply(style, axis=None).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df_b', index=False)
writer.save()
```

This results in the following:
[image]